# Use reflection to iterate over class members

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class with numerous parameters of various types. I want to iterate over all type A members , and run a specific functions ( A.doSomething() )

This doesn't even compile: The conversion from field to XPathDataElement is illegal

```
Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
  for (Field field : fields) {
     if (field. getType().getName().equals(XPathDataElement.class.getName()))
        {               
                tmp = (XPathDataElement)field; // Doesn't compile
                sb.append(field.getName() + ":"); 
                tmp.update();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need top provide more specifics about what you want and why... the example code and description are not clear enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hard to debug your code when you don't say what's wrong with it.

Two things I can see:

1. There's no need to compare strings to decide if the field's type is the right class.

   ```
   if (field.getType().equals(XPathDataElement.class))
   ```

   should work.

   **Edit:** Steve Reed [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721594/use-reflection-to-iterate-over-class-members/721657#721657) that you don't necessarily need it to be exactly `XPathDataElement`; a subclass will work just as well. To check if the field can be treated as an `XPathDataElement`, you should use [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)).

   ```
   if (XPathDataElement.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()))
   ```

   would be the code.
2. I guess your real question is how to get the value of a field reflectively? If so, then [`Field.get(Object)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)) is what you want. The object that you pass to `get()` is the one whose field you want to retrieve; if you're operating on `this` (which is a *strong* code smell), then your code would be

   ```
   XPathDataElement tmp = (XPathDataElement) field.get(this);
   ```

Comment: You're absolutely right about your first comment , I've edited the post. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest avoiding reflection unless you really need it.

Just write the code out:

```
this.x.doSomething();
this.y.doSomething();
this.z.doSomething();
```

Or if you like:

```
for (A a : new A[] {
    this.x, this.y, this.z
}) {
    a.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why I shouldn't use reflection? thanks!

Comment: you lose compile time safety, it will be a bit slower, generally you should use interfaces over reflection to ensure that things are there.  Compile time safety is one of the big pluses in Java (for some it is also one of the downsides).  Can you elaborate more on why you want to use reflection?

Comment: What TofuBear said, plus: It's more code and code which is easier to get wrong and difficult to follow. Reflection and (mobile code) security don't mix very well either.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of pointers:

1. Compare the classes for equality, not their names.

   field.getType().equals(XPathDataElement.class)
2. Or better yet, use `isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)` to handle the case where the class declares a return type as a sublclass of what you're looking for

   XPathDataElement.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
3. You're iterating over **fields**, not **method**. Your question leads me to assume you want the latter, and if so, use:

   this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to assign anything to the `obj` that you cast to `XPathDataElement` in the loop.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
tmp = (XPathDataElement)field.get(this);
```